# create custom physical dynamic page routing in asp.net

Tags: webforms, url-routing

I am using custom routing in asp.net

i have create dynamic page URL Like

```
1) www.xxxxxx.com/post/Home.aspx
2) www.xxxxxx.com/post/aboutus.aspx
3) www.xxxxxx.com/post/profile.aspx
```

in 1) URL  ~/form/Home.aspx is physical exists
but 2) and 3) URL Not physical exists in server

so my problem is how to check "router"  physical exists and dynamic page In URL

If `~/form/Home.aspx` is physical exists then use this `~/post/Home.aspx` page but `.aspx` page physical not exists then use `~/post/common.aspx`

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", "post/{pagename}.aspx", "~/form/{pagename}.aspx");
            System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route2", "post/{pagename}.aspx", "~/form/common.aspx"); 
        }
```

Plz help me

Answer (score 1):

I think your routing is wrong.

```
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", "post/Home.aspx", "~/form/Home.aspx"); // <- the difference is here
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route2", "post/{pagename}.aspx", "~/form/common.aspx");
```

This routing table, will cause Home.aspx to go directly to ~/form/Home.aspx, but all other requests will go to common.aspx.

Shimshon